# How to fetch MySQLi data order by array values?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, sorting, custom-sort

I have created an array, it is used to fetch data from MySQL server.

```
$ids = array(249853, 245549, 249851, 245552, 245551, 249854, 245550, 282445, 261747, 249852, 222398, 248072, 248390, 272473, 219212, 234140, 249815, 241089, 271940, 274940);

$sorted_ids = implode($ids, ",");
```

Fetched data using $sorted_ids which is ID to retrieve, but it is retrieved data by ID ascending order

```
$sql = "SELECT ID, number FROM table WHERE ID IN ({$sorted_ids})";
$result = mysqli_query($connection, $sql);
```

I have tried using == but it is showing only indexes matched records others not.

```
$i = 0;
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    if( $ids[$i] == $row['ID'] ) {
        echo $row['ID']."<br>";

        $i++;
    }
}
```

It is showing records if both indexes matched not other records.

How can I display records by $ids array list ?

Comment: What are you actually trying to achieve? Your code as you say will print out each ID you have retrieved when it matches the ID from your array... Are you wanting the data to be printed in order of the ID's in the array?

Comment: @Zachary yes, exactly

Comment: @Zachary I wanted to print data in order of the IDs in the array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easiest way to do what you want is to the order it within your SQL

```
$sql = "SELECT ID, number FROM table WHERE ID IN ({$sorted_ids}) ORDER BY FIELD(id, {$sorted_ids})";
```

Should do the trick

Comment: it is ordering data by the array values perfectly, thank you